# Outputting the Group Id:Artifact Id in the reactor instead of just the artifact id

Tags: java, maven

When I run a maven command such as "mvn install" or "mvn validate", maven will output the artifact ids of all projects that it builds. I want to use this output in a script to then call something similar to the following command:

```
mvn clean install -pl <comma separated list of groupId:artifactId>
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find how to get maven to output the group Id as well as the artifact Id. I've combed through the maven reactor and dependency plugins so far, but haven't had any luck. Is there any way to do this?

Edit: Turns out you can use just the artifact Id if you put a colon in front of it. E.g

```
mvn clean install -pl :fooProject,:barProject
```

Comment: Having read Jigar Joshi's comment, I created a local copy of Maven that has the functionality I want. I'm speaking with the Maven devs to see if I can get my option to output groupId:artifactId committed to the next release of Maven.

Answer (score 2):

maven doesn't support this by default, it is hard fixed that it will output project's name

[here](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/a90d71e024b7bc0f09e8c33908e3ce936e98df97/maven-embedder/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/cli/event/ExecutionEventLogger.java#L126) is the relevant source

```
private void logReactorSummary( MavenSession session )
{
    logger.info( chars( '-', LINE_LENGTH ) );

    logger.info( "Reactor Summary:" );

    logger.info( "" );

    MavenExecutionResult result = session.getResult();

    for ( MavenProject project : session.getProjects() )
    {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder( 128 );

        buffer.append( project.getName() );
        buffer.append( ' ' );

        if ( buffer.length() <= MAX_PROJECT_NAME_LENGTH )
        {
            while ( buffer.length() < MAX_PROJECT_NAME_LENGTH )
            {
                buffer.append( '.' );
            }
            buffer.append( ' ' );
        }

        BuildSummary buildSummary = result.getBuildSummary( project );

        if ( buildSummary == null )
        {
            buffer.append( "SKIPPED" );
        }
        else if ( buildSummary instanceof BuildSuccess )
        {
            buffer.append( "SUCCESS [" );
            String buildTimeDuration = formatDuration( buildSummary.getTime() );
            int padSize = MAX_PADDED_BUILD_TIME_DURATION_LENGTH - buildTimeDuration.length();
            if ( padSize > 0 )
            {
                buffer.append( chars( ' ', padSize ) );
            }
            buffer.append( buildTimeDuration );
            buffer.append( "]" );
        }
        else if ( buildSummary instanceof BuildFailure )
        {
            buffer.append( "FAILURE [" );
            String buildTimeDuration = formatDuration( buildSummary.getTime() );
            int padSize = MAX_PADDED_BUILD_TIME_DURATION_LENGTH - buildTimeDuration.length();
            if ( padSize > 0 )
            {
                buffer.append( chars( ' ', padSize ) );
            }
            buffer.append( buildTimeDuration );
            buffer.append( "]" );
        }

        logger.info( buffer.toString() );
    }
}
```

if you still want to do it, checkout source code, update this method to output the way you want build maven and start using your local build of maven